# TypeError: Cannot destructure property when fetching data from an API. Can anyone explain this?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, openweathermap

It is my first time working with an API and I'm having a little trouble here. I spent several hours today trying to figure this out, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Would somebody be so kind to explain what's wrong with my code?

I'm trying to get data from the OpenWeather API. It usually works the first time It runs but then I'll just get this error in the console: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'temp' of 'data.main' as it is undefined.
As the method is called every 100 ms it just keeps flooding the console with this error. What's the matter here?

```
    /*Geolocation*/

let latUser = []
let lonUser = []


const errorCallback = (error) => {console.error(error)}
const successCallback = (position) => {
    latUser.push(position.coords.latitude)
    lonUser.push(position.coords.longitude)}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback) 

/*Weather*/

const weatherText = document.querySelector(".wtext")
const weatherCelsius = document.querySelector(".wcelsius")
const weatherHumidity = document.querySelector(".whumid")
const weatherIcon = document.querySelector(".weather-icon")

let weather = {
    "apiKey": "*****",
    fetchWeather: function () {
        fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latUser[0] + "&lon=" + lonUser[0] +
         "&units=metric&appid=" + this.apiKey
        ).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => this.displayWeather(data))
    },
    displayWeather: function(data){
        const { temp, humidity } = data.main
        const { description, icon } = data.weather[0]
        
        
        weatherText.innerText = description
        weatherCelsius.innerText = temp + "°C"
        weatherHumidity.innerText = "Humidity: " + humidity + "%"
        weatherIcon.innerHTML = '<img src="icons/' + icon + '.png">'

    }
}

setInterval(() => {weather.fetchWeather()
    
}, 100);
```

Comment: _"As the method is called every 100 ms..."_ - Why? The weather report won't change every 0.1 seconds...

Comment: You would need a "Professional" subscription to be able to send 6000 requests per minute o.O

Comment: Lol, sorry. You are right, I changed it to 1000 ms. It still floods the console with error tho (just slower). If I don't set an interval it just doesn't work at all and throws the same error (but only once)